# Create list column with Name different from DisplayName

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Creating column with following PS code:

```
$fieldXMLString = '<Field Type="Text"
Name="MyField"
DisplayName="My Field"
StaticName="MyField"
InternalName="MyField"></Field>'
$list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXMLString,$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
```

Result:

```
SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens    : <Field Type="Text" Name="My_x0020_Field" DisplayName="My Field" StaticName="MyField" InternalName="MyField" ID="{4d5e1282-6c52-450b-9f5b-2a37126a9713}" 
                             SourceID="{9b93722f-ce19-4c0b-948b-ba2a6c197539}" ColName="nvarchar11" RowOrdinal="0" />
```

I need **Name** property to be *"MyField"*, not *"My_x0020_Field"*. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is an annoying problem.

You'll find the same behavioud with the UI. Infact, SharePoint define the "name" with the "DisplayName", even if you define manually the "name".

I suggest to change DisplayName for "MyField". Then After adding the column to the list, change the displayName for "My Field". It isn't sexy but it's work.

Here is the code :

```
$field= demoList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MyField");
$field.Title = "My Field";
$field.PushChangesToLists = $true;
$field.Update(true);           
$list.Update();
```

*Edit the code :)*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Thibault!
Mark as an answer since I haven't find a better solution. Hope there's one...
First line of you code not PowerShell BTW.